# Switch from a site cart to the woocommerce shopping cart to make the payment

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

When a product pricelist / license key combination states that the product should be handled by the external shopping cart, Taopix Control Centre will first create a web session as normal but instead of returning with the URL of the Taopix shopping cart it will, instead, call and pass the initialisation parameters to the initialise function within the external script EDL_ExternalShoppingCart.php.

The input to the function is a single PHP associative array that receives all of the parameters to be transferred to the external shopping cart (see below for a list of parameters). The output of this function is also a PHP associative array that communicates the result of the initialisation back to Taopix Control Centre.

```
function initialise($pParamArray){
$result = Array(); $result['result'] = ''; $result['usecustomshoppingcart'] = true;
$result['shoppingcarturl'] = ''; return $result;}
```

I have the API of this web application but I don't know how to make them connect to woocommerce